# One domain, multiple apps, multiple load balancers on AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

The current setup looks like

- On a single EC2 instance, foo.web http/https traffic is handled by nginx, and routed based on:

  - foo.web/bar/* requests are handled by app #2
  - all other foo.web requests are handled by app #1

The goal is to move both apps onto their own ec2 boxes, so we can take advantage of load balancing.

How would one achieve this in AWS?

Bonus points if it doesn't require spinning up another instance to handle routing.

Comment: Please tell us more about your application, if they need a database, where the database is. What you're suggesting is just moving applications onto different boxes. A better approach may be one load balancer and auto scaling up and down so more instances are created when the load is high.

Comment: "Is this possible in AWS?" Yes, of course.

Comment: @EEAA clarified :)

Comment: @Tim The main issue is how one achieves routing /bar/* requests to one app versus another if nginx is not handling that logic

Comment: You're asking us to do your job for you. :) How do *you* think this might work?

Comment: @EEAA well, it'd be possible to do it with an nginx box handling all requests to foo.web, and then passing them off to LB1 and LB2 based on who should get it, but I don't know if there's a more AWS-native way to do it.

Comment: Just keep doing it using Nginx, scale horizontally rather than by separating applications onto boxes.

Comment: @Tim Rob-d's solution allows for baking images for a single application, rather than having deploys touch both apps.

Comment: Based on my understanding of your rather ambiguous question I don't think that's a great solution, but I'm finding this question quite confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can load balance the servers using an AWS load balancer, off load ssl, run health checks and write a policy for the backend servers. but you can't route based on http headers, the ELB doesn't process application requests at that layer - so you will need another instance behind the load balancer to route or proxy. I think because the cloud infrastructure components have to be available in the control panel, CLI and API. It's hard to imagine doing what you want to do solely through the CLI or API. this would be part of an more 'advanced' load balancers bread and butter - HA proxy could be your backend LB and handle the routing too. - hope that helps.